# Wildcard in subdomain for ACL in HAPROXY

Tags: regex, routes, haproxy

Trying to match the following in haproxy:

`acl instagiveweb hdr_beg(host) -i foo*.something.com`

where the url could be `foo-staging.something.com` or `foo.something.com`

I've looked through the docs at https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/acls.html#data-types-and-matching-between-samples-and-patterns but having a hard time finding the pattern matching that I need.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: If a regex is accepted, try `acl instagiveweb hdr_beg(host) -i foo[^.]*.something.com` or `acl instagiveweb hdr_beg(host) -i foo(-staging)?.something.com`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want `hdr_reg()` ("reg"ex), not `hdr_beg()` (literal string prefix/"beg"inning).

```
acl instagiveweb hdr_reg(host) -i ^foo[^\.]*\.example\.com$
```

This should match the entire host header only if begins with `foo` followed by 0 or more of any character except `.` followed by `.example.com` at the end of the value.