# Rancher behind haproxy

Tags: docker, haproxy, rancher

I have some small cluster managed with Rancher. There are only two workers : **node1** and **node2**.

I could add a **stack1**, add a load-balancer for this stack or global and it works fine. But I have some problem with DNS.

I could point **stack1.domain.com** to **node1.domain.com** for example. My load-balancer is running on the node1 (or even on all the nodes of my cluster) so it works.

But if one day I need to shut down my node1, I have to go quickly and point DNS stack1.domain.com to node2.domain.com
Not a good idea.

My first thought was to use a small haproxy server in front of my Rancher cluster.

So, I point **stack1.domain.com** to **haproxy.domain.com** and then haproxy backend it to node1 and node2.

But it does not work.

I could put something like that

```
frontend  http *:80
    acl stack1           hdr(host)       -i stack1.domain.com
    use_backend bck_s1          if stack1

backend bck_s1
    mode http
    balance     roundrobin
    server      n1 node1.domain.com:80 check
    server      n2 node2.domain.com:80 check
```

Probably it could work. But if I need to add stack2 that listen on 80 port as well, I could not use this schema.

I could add **bck_s2**, but it will point to the same **node1/node2**. So rancher will not understand if I want stack1 or stack2?

It's possible to resolve it using different ports, but it seems not a good idea. Certainly I could listen stack1 to 80 port, stack2 to 8080, but if I have stack3, 4,... it became too complex.

I had an idea to add some path to backend. Like this :

```
backend bck_s1
    mode http
    balance     roundrobin
    server      n1 node1.domain.com:80/s1 check
    server      n2 node2.domain.com:80/s1 check
```

In this case I could put a load-balancer on the Rancher based on rule /s1,  /s2 etc.
But it seems that it's not possible to do this using haproxy. Am I right?

So the questions.

1) Is it possible to realize it using haproxy and how to do it?

2) Are there some others solutions that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using specific entries in `haproxy.domain.com`, you could configure a wildcard entry, point to both the nodes along with configuring healthcheck for the backend. That way when you take down node-1, HA proxy can detect it and not direct traffic to that node anymore. Things would be more dynamic this way on the HA Proxy side and you wouldn't need to make DNS changes.

References:
- [Wildcard in subdomain for ACL in HAPROXY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194891/wildcard-in-subdomain-for-acl-in-haproxy)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That make a sense, but I still have a problem how to configure load-balancer on Rancher? Or how to pass information to this load-balancer from haproxy?
For example, using wildcard entry I got request for stack1 or stack2 on haproxy.
I redirect it to node1 or node2... but how to indicate for these nodes which stack I want?

Comment: I do not have a 1.6.x setup handy to provide the actual configs. But the idea is to create a global load balancer stack and then create the rules that you want pointing to the corresponding stacks. You need to choose "Always run one instance of this container on every host." when launching the LB.